# Heaviside multivariable integral on a finite domain

Tags: integration, special-functions, trigonometric-integrals

I have an integral of the form

$$I=\int_0^{\ell_p}dp_1\int_0^{\ell_p}dp_2\theta\left(-\lambda+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi p_1}{\ell_p}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi p_2}{B\ell_p}\right)\right),$$
Where $B,\ell_p$ are real constants and $\lambda\in(-2,2)$.

My EFFORT:

I know that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\theta(u(x,y))dxdy=\int_{\Omega}1dxdy$$ where $\Omega=\{(x,y) :u(x,y)>0\}$
Am I right in assuming that for my case we have
$$I=\int_{\tilde{\Omega}}1dp_1dp_2,$$
where $\tilde{\Omega}=\{(p_1,p_2):0<u(p_1,p_2)<u(\ell_p,\ell_p)\},$ and $u(p_1,p_2)=-\lambda+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi p_1}{\ell_p}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi p_2}{B\ell_p}\right)$?

Now from this:

The condition $0<u(p_1,p_2)$ gives $$p_2>\pm\frac{\ell_pB}{2\pi}\arccos\left(\lambda-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi p_1}{\ell_p}\right)\right)+2\pi k,$$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

The condition $u(p_1,p_2)<u(\ell_p,\ell_p)$
gives
$$p_2<\pm\frac{\ell_pB}{2\pi}\arccos\left(1+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{B}\right)-2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi p_1}{\ell_p}\right)\right)+2\pi m$$
where $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Taking $m,k=0$ and taking the positive branch we have
$$I=\int_0^{\ell_p}\int_{\frac{\ell_pB}{2\pi}\arccos\left(\lambda-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi p_1}{\ell_p}\right)\right)}^{\frac{\ell_pB}{2\pi}\arccos\left(1+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{B}\right)-2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi p_1}{\ell_p}\right)\right)}dp_2dp_1\\
=\int_0^{\ell_p}\frac{\ell_pB}{2\pi}\arccos\left(1+\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{B}\right)-2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi p_1}{\ell_p}\right)\right)-\frac{\ell_pB}{2\pi}\arccos\left(\lambda-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi p_1}{\ell_p}\right)\right)dp_1.$$

And so far I can't seem to solve this integral, explicitly at least...

I have tried letting $\cos(z)=\lambda-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi p_1}{\ell_p}\right)$ but this produces $\pm$ signs when looking the derivatives and when looking at the limits and I'm not sure on which branches to take etc., some help with this would be greatly appreciated also.

Comment: $\theta$ is your name for the Heaviside function, $\theta(x)=0$ if $x<0$ and $=1$ if $x>0$, right?   Are your $p_i$ integers? If so, you might as well take $p_1=p_2=1$, as the distribution of values of $\cos(kt)$ over a full period $0\le t<\pi$ does not depend on $k$

Comment: Yes $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside function, the $p_i$s are not integers they are integration variables and so are continuous in the interval $[0,\ell_p)$.

Comment: Careless reading on my part.   Sorry.

Comment: no problem, I can't seem to find anything about the Heaviside step function restricted to a finite domain, I thing once I understand this I will be able to progress with my problem quickly.